# How to set swiper left and righ swipe limit?

Tags: android, jquery, slider, swipe, swiper.js

How can I make the left and right limit from swiper to be less??
If I am on the first slide and if I swipe to right there is a threshhold and I see the wrapper. How can I minimise this so that the distance is shorter.. for example at the responsive design example:
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php

Comment: Can you please tell me why you thumbed down my question? If you didn't understood my question ask further... If you think its to common please answer it!

Comment: It is impossible to do that easily, only using hack into into onSetWrapperTranslate callback and modify transform offset value. But you can just turn off such bounce behavior by setting resistance:"100%" parameter

Comment: @VladimirKharlampidi Thank you! finally:D... I managed to make the bounce 0 by setting resistance:'100%' as you told me... However I was wonderinh why other values from 0 to 99 doesn't work... They are all the same as the default bounce... only 100% maked the difference.. And I wanted to bounce just a little..

Answer (score 0):

use resistance:'100%' to fix left limit before 1st slide and right last slide to 0

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this response (august 11, 2015) I think the solution is to use `resistanceRatio` property instead of `resistance:'100%'`.
With `resistanceRatio: 0` bounce behavior is turned off. The default value is `0.85`.

This will work if `resistance` property is not false (default value for `resistance` is `true`).